# jQuery - Can't calculate element width on page load?

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window-resize, window-load

I'm doing some work on the active navigation indicator arrow on my personal site: http://staging.rjlacount.com

**The problem**: Navigation indicator arrow will not center under the active item on page load, but will on window resize.

The code I'm using to center the arrow (starting on line 80 of http://staging.rjlacount.com/js/functions.js) is as follows:

```
var $arrowOffset = 8;

var navArrowCenter = function() {
  var $current_page_item = $(".current_page_item a");
  $arrow
    .css("left", $current_page_item.position().left + ( ($current_page_item.width() / 2) - $arrowOffset) );
};

$wind.resize(function() {
    navArrowCenter();
});

$wind.load(function() {
    navArrowCenter();
});
```

I have tried removing the page fade on load functionality, assuming it was causing jQuery to not be able to properly render the element width, but that does not seem to affect the issue at all.

Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing it from the `$(window).load()`?

Try this:

```
  navArrowCenter();
```

Instead of:

```
$wind.load(function() {
    navArrowCenter();
});
```

Comment: Thank you much, that did the trick. Makes sense, too, just need another set of eyes sometimes I guess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because the DOM isn't ready yet. Try it on document `ready` instead of `load`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    navArrowCenter();
});
```

By the way, if that is a [JQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (like it appears to be) then that is something completely different - it is used to load html from another page.

---

After looking at your code, you already have the whole lot inside a `document ready` anyway. So, as @Blowsie has said, just call the function without wrapping it in your `$wind.load`

Comment: it appears all of his code is already inside the document ready function.